# R - Changing colour of plot from plot3d

Tags: rgl

I currently trying to use plot3d function from rgl library.

```
open3d()
x = usage[,5]
y = usage[,6]
z = usage$transfer
plot3d(x,y,z, type='h')
```

I was wondering if anybody can help me change the colour of the lines such that the positive z will be red and the negative z will be blue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by

```
plot3d(x, y, z, type = 'h', col = ifelse(z < 0, 'blue', 'red'))
```